# Does nodejs create background task or child process to execute callback function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, background-process, child-process

Does NodeJS create a background task or child process to execute callback functions? How does NodeJS execute the query below?

```
MyModel.find({}, function (err, docs) {
  //Do some thing
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NodeJs` implements non-blocking `i/o` to achieve these callbacks in single thread. It uses an event-loop.

On demand of data, nodejs registers a callback and send the operation to this event loop. and when data is available, callback is called.

Say a thread is executing callback A. It keep executing, and say it finds another async task. It registers the new callback B for that async task. Meanwhile waiting for data of B, it start executing some other callback C. Once C is completed. Then it check if data of B is available. If so, executes B. Otherwise executes some other callback D... and so on..

read this for deep understanding http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered so many times already... It's not specific to Mongoose, almost every single Javascript library does this to handle asynchronous calls.

Have a look at this presentation from JSConf by Philip Roberts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

It explains really well what actually happens under the hood.

Anyway, what Mongoose basically does is querying MongoDB using the [Node.js MongoDB Native driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/), waiting for a response and executing your callback function with the `err` and `doc` results it recieved from the native driver.

In simple terms, Mongoose is simply a wrapper to the native driver to make things easier for the developer.